# Stuck on a quantifier logic problem

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I've been trying to prove this to no avail..

$\vdash\exists x(Px\rightarrow\forall xPx)$

The book gives a hint.. that it might be helpful to prove the following two before tackling the main problem:

$\{\forall x\neg(Px\rightarrow\forall xPx)\}\vdash\forall xPx$

and

$\{\forall x\neg(Px\rightarrow\forall xPx)\}\vdash \neg \forall xPx$

I proved both of these but I don't know how to apply it to the main problem.

Comment: This is a mess. What does $x$ mean here? Better use separate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you proved from the statement $\forall xPx$ and $\neg\forall xPx$ you can conclude that the statement is wrong. Your result is just the negation of that statement.

EDIT: This is proof by contradiction. You can assume a statement and prove that you can derive a contradiction($P\wedge \neg P$) and then you know that the result is true without depending on the assumption.

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding.. the first problem is meant to be proven from the empty set, while the latter two are not tautologies

Comment: You can assume a statement and prove that you can derive a contradiction($P\wedge \neg P$) and then you know that the result is true without depending on the assumption.
EDIT: I added this into the answer.

Comment: @jamesmchart There's a theorem that if $T,\theta \vdash \phi$ then $A \vdash \theta \to \phi$. And by tautology, if $T \vdash (\theta \to \phi) \land (\theta \to \lnot \phi)$ then $T \vdash \lnot \theta$.

Comment: @fgp: This is not always true if $\theta$ is not a sentence. For example, $(x+x=0)\vdash (y+y=0)$ but absolutely not $\vdash (x+x=0)\rightarrow (y+y=0)$.

Comment: @tomasz Sure, but the problem here is simply that $(\forall x \phi(x)) \to (\forall y \theta(y))$ isn't the same as $\forall x \forall y (\phi(x) \to \theta(y))$.

Comment: @fgp: Which nonetheless shows that the statement is false without any assumptions on $\theta$...

Comment: @tomasz When I write "a formula $\phi$" I always assume the formula is closed. Otherwise I'd write "a formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$", or at least "a formula $\phi$ with free variables". I always found that whole we'll-just-assume-free-variable-are-all-quantified-business hightly dubious - context of quantifiers matters (a lot!), so introducing them implicitly is IMHO an extremely bad idea.

Comment: @fgp - sorry but, in general, the term *formula* does not implicitly assume that it is a "closed" one. A *closed* formula is usually called : *sentence*.

Comment: @fgp: I agree with Mauro here: a closed formula is called a *sentence*, and you should call it that when you want to stress the closedness.

Comment: @tomasz Ok, I cede the point guys ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just prove it semantically (using completeness theorem).

Choose arbitrary model $M$.

If $M\models\forall x P(x)$, then clearly $M$ models the statement in question.

Else there is some $m\in M$ such that $M\models\neg P(m)$. But then clearly $M\models P(m)\rightarrow \forall x P(x)$, and then $M\models\exists x(P(x)\rightarrow \forall x P(x))$.